# annotation column in ef codefirst not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

my namespaces are:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
```

and my class is:

```
public class KalaType
{

[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int kalaID { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int typeID { get; set; }
... 

}
```

But display this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Column' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To use `KeyAttribute` and `ColumnAttribute` you should add the assembly in which they are defined. 
So, you should add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in your project.
 Find it in Reference Manager -> Assemblies -> Framework.

Comment: thanx for your answer.I find it in "Add Reference -> .NET " and click on it. But it say: The Website is already referencing the assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'  !! :(

Comment: Can you switch to 4.5 and try then? Do clean and rebuild.

Comment: how can I switch It to 4.5?

Comment: sorry..I found in my 'Registry Editor ->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'  so it's 4.5

Comment: That means you have 4.5 installed. Now check the settings of your project to see what you are using.

Comment: sorry alterfox..I waste your time... :(  This Error happens for Every annotation that I use! So I want to use another way that dont have 'annotation'..  Thanks for your help.